# htaccess for Leverage browser caching not working

Tags: .htaccess, http, caching, http-headers, browser-cache

I am having issues with Leverage browser caching.
I have created this .htaccess file and am using it on my server but it doesnt appear to be working, i copied this from here "http://www.samaxes.com/2011/05/improving-web-performance-with-apache-and-htaccess/".
I am most likly making a basic mistake so any help would be nice.
here are some details. I am working on a subdomain lets call it "sub" and the main domain "example".
so i want everything in http://sub.example.com/ for the htaccess file to work on.
on my server i placed the .htaccess file in sub's main directory which is seperate to the main one for example.

I am running an apache2 server with both mod_headers and mod_expires enabled also.

Cheers.

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/xhtml+xml application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype font/opentype
</ifModule>
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
 </ifModule>
 <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
 Header set Expires "Sun, 17 July 2013 20:00:00 GMT"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\\.(css|css.gz)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, private" 
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\\.(js|js.gz)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, private"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private, must-revalidate"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
 </filesMatch>
 FileETag None
```

Comment: Did you try `a2enmod expires` followed by `service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

looks very messy.

You also have redundant rules like

`ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"`

and

```
<filesMatch "\\.(js|js.gz)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, private"
</filesMatch>
```

Try using the cleaner (and up to date) rules from the [html5-boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess) or checkout all the 
[**h5bp server configs**](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs)

Answer (score 0):

only use this one and have a try:

```
    <ifModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
 </ifModule>
```

Like @Anthony Hatzopoulos pointed out, you are using duplicate configurations and they might be conflicting. Of course if you like you can use "fileMatch" way as well but the thing is they are not nice code. Please note if you use "fileMatch" then you don't use the  code.